# How to import a js file from landkit inside my vue project

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

actually I m working in  a interisting project and I m using vue with landkit bootstrap,but I don't understand why doesn't work the javascript comportament of landkit component. I need to import the following links.Normally I  import inside my index.html file but in the new version of vue-cli I don't have this file.Somebody can you help me?

```html
<script src="./assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/flickity-fade/flickity-fade.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/aos/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax-video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax-element.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/typed.js/lib/typed.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/countup.js/dist/countUp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/highlightjs/highlight.pack.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method in your `app.js` file

```
import $ from '@/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
```